# Calculate the maximum font-size without triggering a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have a function that proportionately reduces the font size if there is a scroll bar detected, ie, if there is enough content to trigger a scrollbar.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "7px";
  }
  console.log(document.body.scrollHeight);
  console.log(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

li {
  font-size: 4.5em
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <!--if more stuff added - reduce the font size the right amount so there's is no scroll bar present.-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

But as you can see I currently am setting a static font size of 7px, no matter the amount of content on the page. What I am trying to achieve is calculate the maximum font size the content can have, without triggering a scroll bar, depending on the content in the page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the ul has a fixed height?

Comment: Example works....

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on the style of your font. But basically, you need your font size to be - the ul height (or the any scrolling element you'd like to fit into) divided to the number of its children.

```
let ulHeight = document.querySelector('.content ul').clientHeight;
let lisCount = document.querySelector('.content ul').childElementCount; 

let lis = document.querySelectorAll('.content ul li');

[].forEach.call(lis, function(li) {
  li.style.fontSize = Math.floor((ulHeight / lisCount) -2) + 'px' 
});
```

Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8w9hwv7/23/)

In this example, the font style is a little too big to fit the ul perfectly, so I've diminished it in another 2 pixels. 
Noticed I've rounded down the division and the ul height is fixed. 
Modify the ul height or add more lis to see it works.

Comment: What if the there's just one div with a bunch of h2 tags inside?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Then set the height of that div and then change the selectors in my code. the ul should be the div and the li should be the h2.
If you can post your code, i'll show you exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try this one by resizing the window size or changing the content. I have set a maximum font-size of 60px. May be you can change that. Also you may set a min font-size for the sake of readability.

```js
function resize() {
    var defaultSize = 60;
    $('.content').css('font-size', defaultSize + 'px');
    for (i = defaultSize; document.body.scrollHeight > (document.documentElement.clientHeight*.95); i--) {
        $('.content').css('font-size', i + 'px');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    resize();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    resize();
})
```

```css
ul,li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
                <li>Stuff</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Beware infinite loops: add a check that i>=0 in your loop.

Comment: Could you explain `document.documentElement.clientHeight * .95` ?

Comment: also, if i set a minimum font size (suppose `i >= 5`) the scrollbar still shows.

Comment: Could you explain document.documentElement.clientHeight * .95 - this triggers the font resize when the content height reaches 95% of the window height.

Comment: Also, do we need both document.ready and window.resize? -  this check for the correct font size on page load as well as when we resize the window. in case of smartphone, orientation changing scenario can be handled with this.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "7px";
  } else {
     document.body.style.fontSize = "4.5em";
  }
```

```css
body {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>  
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    //if more stuff added - reduce the font size the right amount so there's is no scroll bar present.
  </ul>
</div>
```